# Add errors to VeeValidate errors bag from parent component and listen from child components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I couldn't find a guideline to implement this. How would you add data to errors bag from parent component and listen to the particular error from child components to show something conditionally?

I've added the error to the errors bag from the `parent` component like the following:

```
export default {
  mounted () {
    this.$validator.errors.add('critical', 'Unable to connect', 'network')
  }
}
```

Now, from the `child` component, I'd like to show something conditionally depending on the error bag whether there is an error or not. I've added my child component the following:

```
<a class="navbar-item" v-if="!errors.has('critical')">Hello World</a>
```

The `errors.has('critical')` return `false` as VeeValidate returns a new instance for each component. So, how do I go about transfer the same errors bag from parent component to child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with VeeValidate, however, I guess the Vue way should work just fine no matter what you're using.

There is also probably another way to do it with your library though. Anyway, I'd do it that way:

## Step 1

Emit your event from your parent component's method:

```
let payload = {
    message: 'Unable to connect', 
    type: 'network'
};
this.$emit('error', payload);
```

#Step 2

In your child component, or any component:

```
let self = this;
$on('error', (payload) => {
   self.error = payload;
});
```

#Step 3

You can now access it from the template side in your other component:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" v-if="error.type == 'critical'" v-text="error.message"></div>
```

This is just an example. It's ES6, feel free to translate in other version.

The doc you're looking for is here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events

Comment: Currently I'm using VueX to store the VeeValidate object from the parent component. However, your solution also looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can share the error bag with all yours components. You have to just inject the  validator into component
Here you can find a documentation:
https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/advanced/#injection

and here you can take a look at some examples of usages:
https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/issues/468#issuecomment-305189771